# Convert cursor output to list of geometries

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, array

I want to convert all the geometries returned by search cursor to a list.

```
import math
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\GIS Data\GIS data_for Maeenul vai"

desc = arcpy.Describe("River.shp")
shapefieldname = desc.ShapeFieldName

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor("River.shp")

featureList = []

for row in rows:

    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)
    featureList.append(feat)

    print "%i %i" % (feat.firstPoint.X, feat.firstPoint.Y)
    print
    print "%i %i" % (feat.lastPoint.X, feat.lastPoint.Y)
    print
    print

del row, rows
print "---------------------------------------------------------------"

for feat in featureList:
    print "%i %i" % (feat.firstPoint.X, feat.firstPoint.Y)
    print
    print "%i %i" % (feat.lastPoint.X, feat.lastPoint.Y)
    print
    print
    print
```

Output is

> 3610930 2135882 3611593 2134453
>
> 3611806 2134981 3611593 2134453
>
> 3614160 2136164 3617432 2131734
>
> 3611593 2134453 3617432 2131734
>
> 3617432 2131734 3620568 2127591
>
> 3620568 2127591 3620785 2127423
>
> 3617980 2126657 3620568 2127591
>
> 3616768 2129454 3617948 2126649
>
> 3617948 2126649 3617980 2126657
>
> 3615102 2128889 3617587 2126510
>
> 3617587 2126510 3617948 2126649
>
> 3617624 2126416 3617980 2126657
>
> 3613129 2128176 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615155 2125617 3617587 2126510
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> ---
>
> **List Data**
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617
>
> 3615086 2125515 3615155 2125617

So basically the append methods of list only copies the last element returned by cursor to the whole list. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

try to use:

```
....
arr = arcpy.Array()
firstPoint = arcpy.Point()
lastPoint = arcpy.Point()

for row in rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)
    firstPoint.X = feat.firstPoint.X
    firstPoint.Y = feat.firstPoint.Y

    lastPoint.X = feat.lastPoint.X
    lastPoint.Y = feat.lastPoint.Y

    arr.add(lastPoint)
    arr.add(lastPoint)
```

more information [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000005r000000).

i hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks! After posting on SO, I also got the same idea. I wonder why ArcGIS is doing such weird thing?

Answer (score 2):

That append should work, from Python help:

> list.append(x) Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to
>   a[len(a):] = [x].

Try deleting the variable in the loop and see if that clears up the problem.  If not, try the long hand method of:

`featurelist[len(featurelist):] = [feat]`

Comment: I've also tried this. Nothing's working!!!

Comment: The only reason I said that was because you repeated the feat var, but that shouldn't really be an issue...

Answer (score 2):

What you have should work fine for a field that is not a geometry field. Try another field that is in the table to test. Example for a point shapefile:

```
for row in rows:
# Create the geometry object 'feat'
#
feat = row.getValue(shapefieldname)
pnt = feat.getPart()

# Print x,y coordinates of current point
#
print pnt.X, pnt.Y
featureList.append(pnt)
```

Notice you get the Value and then the part. More info here: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reading_geometries/002z0000001t000000/

You will see that the example for line or polygon steps through the parts:

```
# Step through each part of the feature
#
for part in feat:
    # Print the part number
    #
    print "Part %i:" % partnum

    # Step through each vertex in the feature
    #
    for pnt in feat.getPart(partnum):
        if pnt:
            # Print x,y coordinates of current point
            #
            print pnt.X, pnt.Y
        else:
            # If pnt is None, this represents an interior ring
            #
            print "Interior Ring:"
    partnum += 1
```

The Value you return from getValue is that of a geometry object, which returns them in an array of point objects.<- (also from the help) Word up.